# SQL Report Group by field (listbox item selection)

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, listboxitems

I am new to SQL Reporting. I have created a report(.rdl) file using SQL Server 2008 R2, SQL Server Business  Intelligence Development Studio by using online help. 
The report displays 2 fields. Student_Category  and No. of Students.
Now, I am trying to sort the Student_Category by list box where the user  can choose ‘All’ as well as group by individual ‘Student_Category’. 
Any help given is appreciated. Please guide me through the steps

Thanks for your help in advance,
Ken.

Answer (score 0):

while this suggestion is what I've done for 2005, and I'm not sure if 2008 makes it any easier, in 2005 what I would do is add an "All" row to my data set for the drop down with some unique key that the real data set couldn't have (like a GUID full of zeros). Then in my where clause of the SQL I'd have something like

```
((@StudentCategory = '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}') OR (@StudentCategory = Student_Category))
```

When the value is "All" then the condition would be true without filtering records, and when that's false, the records would be filtered by the Student_Category.